# How to pass a parameter from a SearchBox to a fetch url in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two React stateful Components - SearchBox and FetchMusic. My plan is for the SearchBox component to receive input from the user and pass it into a fetch url in my FetchMusic component (using template string). My code is below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SearchBox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: ''
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({value: e.target.value});
  }
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let userInput = this.state.value;
    this.props.onSearchBox(userInput); 
    console.log(`You searched for the movie ${userInput}`);      
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="search-container">
        <form className="form-search" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input 
            type="text" 
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            placeholder="Search Movie Title..."
          />
        </form>
        <h5>{this.state.value}</h5>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchBox;
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SearchBox from './SearchBox';

class FetchMovie extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoad: false,
      data: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const fetchConfig = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    };
    
    fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=dfbcc791&t=${<SearchBox onSearchBox={this.handleSubmit} />}`, fetchConfig)
      .then(res =>  res.json())
      .then(movies => { 
        this.setState({
          isLoad: false,
          data: movies
        });
      },
        (error) => { 
          this.setState({
            isLoad: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  // }
  }
  render() {
    const { error, isLoad, data } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return (
        <div>Error: {console.log(error.message)}</div>
      );
    } else if (isLoad) {
      return (
      <div>{console.log('Loading. . . . .')}</div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div className="display">
          <div className="column1">
            <img src={data.Poster} alt="Movie"></img>
          </div>
          <div className="column2">
            <h3> Title: {data.Title}</h3>
            <h6>Actors: {data.Actors}</h6>
            <h6>Year: {data.Year}</h6>
            <h6>Runtime: {data.Runtime}</h6>
            <h6>Rated: {data.Rated}</h6>
            <p>Plot: {data.Plot}</p>
          </div>
          <div>{console.log(data.Title +' '+ data.Actors)}</div>
        </div>
        
      );
    }    
  }
}

export default FetchMovie;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import NavBar from './components/NavBar';
import SearchBox from './components/SearchBox';
import FetchMovie from './components/FetchMovie';
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <NavBar />,
      <SearchBox />
      <FetchMovie />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I write on the input box and click Enter, I get an error with the following message:

> "TypeError: this.props.onSearchBox is not a function
> SearchBox/this.handleSubmit"

Your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you putting your search box component in your fetch url? Components should only be rendered, not used like a function. This is not doing what you think it is doing. The error specifically is happening because in your app component, you are not passing it the onSearch box prop.

Comment: @SpeedOfRounds Thanks for contribution.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to correct:

1. You're not passing a prop called `onSearchBox` when you're using `<SearchBox />` in the JSX of the `App` component.
2. In the `FetchMovie` component, the URL is wrong since you should place the search string but not the component itself.

something like this:

```
fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=dfbcc791&t=${enteredString}`
```

not

```
fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=dfbcc791&t=${<SearchBox onSearchBox={this.handleSubmit} />}`
```

3. You should maintain a new state in the `App` component to handle the state of the entered search string(to pass it to the `FetchMovie` component) and to check if it is submitted to display the `FetchMovie` component.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how do I now get the  value from the Search box??

Comment: @Chinonso - There are multiple questions on transferring data between components. Look through them.